# Evaluating expressions involving roots of cubic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of "roots"; could someone please solve this problem and explain the logic behind their method?

If $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the roots of $x^3+2x^2-3x+4$, find:

1. $\alpha\beta\gamma,$
2. $\alpha+\beta+\gamma,$
3. $\dfrac{1}{\alpha}+\dfrac{1}{\beta}+\dfrac{1}{\gamma},$
4. $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2.$

Comment: That's not a quadratic equation...

Comment: Google for "Math StackExchange LaTeX guide".

Comment: 1. That's a cubic equation, not a quadratic. 2. Look up Vieta's formulae 3. You should start with some genuine effort (something should have been covered in your course work) before anyone can help you here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please note a well-written question on MSE generally involves [using LaTeX for mathematical formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), showing your motivation and research effort. Your question has been edited to improve formatting. Please also notice the equation you are giving is not quadratic (as was (initially) stated in the title), it is cubic.

Comment: Sorry everyone for the formatting errors (I'll work on it) ; I'm new to this site.

Answer (score 2):

Given $x=\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of the equation $x^3+2x^2-3x+4=0$

So using factor theorem, $x-\alpha,x-\beta,x-\gamma$ are the factors of given equation.

So $$x^3+2x^2-3x+4 = (x-\alpha)\cdot (x-\beta)\cdot (x-\gamma)$$

$$\displaystyle x^3+2x^2-3x+4=x^3-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)x^2+(\alpha\cdot \beta+\beta\cdot \gamma+\gamma\cdot \alpha)x-\alpha\cdot \beta\cdot \gamma$$

Now Camparing Coefficients, We get

$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma = -2$$ and $$\alpha\cdot \beta+\beta\cdot \gamma+\gamma\cdot \alpha=-3$$ and $$\alpha\beta\gamma = -4$$

So $$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 = (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\cdot \beta+\beta\cdot \gamma+\gamma\cdot \alpha) =10$$

So $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}+\frac{1}{\gamma} = \frac{\alpha\cdot \beta+\beta\cdot \gamma+\gamma\cdot \alpha}{\alpha\beta\gamma}=\frac{3}{4}$$